# How does Geth query the blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, nodes, clients

This question has probably been already answered somewhere else but I didn't find anything on the internet so I'm asking here.
I wonder how clients such as Geth query the blockchain to get specific information like a transaction or some address' balance. If you search by transaction hash you can get anything you're looking for in a couple of seconds, but how does the client actually fetch data from the blockchain? I know Ethereum is backed by LevelDB, but I still don't get how it is possible to skim through the entire blockchain is such little time.
Maybe I'm getting something wrong, thanks in advace!

Answer (score 1):

> I think this [article](https://hackernoon.com/getting-deep-into-ethereum-how-data-is-stored-in-ethereum-e3f669d96033) is going to help for what you looking for.